# Using the Gradient theorem along a parabolic path in 3D

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Check the fundamental theorem for gradient using $T=x^{2}+4xy+2yz^{3}$ from the point a = $\left ( 0,0,0 \right )$ to point b$=\left ( 1,1,1 \right )$

along the parabolic path where $z=x^{2}\ and\ y = x$

By definition:

$\vec{\nabla}T=\left \langle 2x+4y,4+2z^{3}6yz^{2} \right \rangle$

Looking at the xy-plane, we break the triangular path into the vertical and horizontal component

Along the horizontal component:

$d\vec{l}=\left \langle dx,0,0 \right \rangle where y=0\ and\ z=0$

Then,

$\int_{x=0}^{x=1}\vec{\nabla}T.d\vec{l}=1$

Along the vertical component:

$d\vec{l}=\left \langle 0,dy,0 \right \rangle$ 
where x=1 and z=0

Then,

$\int_{y=0}^{y=1}\vec{\nabla}T.d\vec{l}=4$

Along the path where the path goes from the xy-plane to the z-plane for which z=1

$d\vec{l}=\left \langle 0,0,dz \right \rangle$
Here, as given by the question $y=x\ and\ z=x^{2}$

Also, note that at all point where the path extends from $\left \langle 1,1,0 \right \rangle to \left \langle 1,1,1 \right \rangle$

we have x=y=1

Integrating over the z-component

$\int_{z=0}^{z=1}\vec{\nabla}T.d\vec{l}=\int_{z=0}^{z=1}6yz^{2}=2yz^{3}=2y=2 (since\ y=1)$

Is this correct? I haven't utilised the given information $z=x^{2}$

Comment: Does no one have any answers to this question?